# rerouting nested resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I have this in my routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

It creates the show path `/users/:user_id/posts/:post_id`

Great. But if someone types `/users/:user_id/post/:post_id` (mind the singular /post and not /posts) then they get a 404. I want to do a 302 redirect from `.../post/:post_id` to `../posts/:post_id` in my routes. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to achieve that by using the following in your routes config.

```
get '/users/:user_id/post/:post_id', to: redirect('/users/%{user_id}/posts/%{post_id}')
```

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html Section: 3.12 Redirection

Comment: Yup. That'll do. You do need to specify the status in the redirect and you shouldn't have a space between redirect and the opening parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, sorry that was a typo. If you need more info regarding the redirect options you can see the source in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html